# AngularJS: add, remove and reorder items controlled by array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat in a table.  There are several of these tables inside a larger table. Each row has buttons for "add another" (which I have working) and remove current row/move row up-down (which I don't).

[image]

They are created with an array, each group in the table has its own array, with one member to start.

```
  vm.choices1 = [{ id: 'choice1' }];
  vm.choices2 = [{ id: 'choice1' }];
  vm.choices3 = [{ id: 'choice1' }];
```

Clicking the plus button passes the current array and pushes a new item onto it, thus adding a repeater.

```
vm.addNewChoice = function(arr) {
 var newItemNo = arr.length + 1;
  arr.push({
    'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
  });
};
```

This works fine.  Of course, now I have been asked to add the delete button and up/down buttons.

I get in concept what I need to do: I suppose somehow when the delete button is clicked I need to pass that index number to a delete function and pop that index from the array thats passed:

```
vm.deleteChoice = function(arr) {
    arr.splice(index, index+1); //??
};
```

But I'm not sure how to get and pass the clicked index to the function. I used to know how to do this in jQuery, but not in Angular.  If I can get the index of the clicked item into my function, I'm sure I can figure out the u/down buttons from there too.

Basic punker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WPdnmYbDSXC0LsbeMduM?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive `ng-repeat` creates a scope for every item that it iterates through. Part of the data assigned to this scope is the attribute `$index` which will be equal to the index in the array of the item/object.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: $Index!  I forgot about that. This seems to work `ng-click="carrier.deleteChoice(carrier.choices1,this.$index)"` sent to `vm.deleteChoice = function(arr, index) { arr.splice(index, index); }` in the controller.

Comment: Actually, thats a good idea and helped me with my next issue!  I guess I nee to brush up on `splice`